# Programmatic Access to TypeScript Call Stack

Tags: typescript, console.log, callstack

I am working on a TypeScript debug tool and ran into the problem that I don't seem to be able to access the TypeScript call stack programmatically.

When I do this:

```
   const error = new Error();
   console.log(error.stack);
```

I get the expected result and can see the TypeScript call stack.

But if I do this:

```
   const error = new Error();
   const errorStack = error.stack;
   console.log(errorStack);
```

I get only get the JavaScript stack instead of the expected TypeScript stack.

The problem sees to be how or when source-maps are applied.

Is there a way to get the same information I get as console output in the first example into a TypeScript/JavaScript variable? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post examples of the two call stacks you're seeing? Since your code is valid javascript, there should be no difference in behavior compared to vanila javascript.
You can see this in [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIgxCBAZykQFMAnKuKxAXkTAoHdEBRGuzAbn0LEwJOABsKAOlFwA5mmq0qEsgEMIAawz8AvrlyhIsBIgBGKqphwCCQspW70mLdl0V9rRUuQV0AylDV1RntFZQCNfkJPYTFJaTkfKn9ArVxdfVR3MwstIA).

Comment: @CameronLittle The TypeScript playground doesn't seem to be using source maps, so you'll always see the JavaScript call stack and never the TypeScript call stack. See my follow up post below with an example to reproduce the issue in Chrome.